# How can i make my app run even when app is killed? killed in the sense when it is removed from recent apps

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am developing an app which can count number of unlocks in whole day.

I have seen many similar questions but none of them worked!! Anyone that can help me please provide code snippet for the above question.

Even make sure the solutoin you provide works for Android O and above

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MyReceiver myReceiver;
IntentFilter filter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
}}
```

MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   private static final String TAG = "BroadCast Receiver";
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
          Toast.makeText(context, "DEVICE_IS_UNLOCKED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Log.i(TAG, "Unlocked");
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start services in foreground
https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/?

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//$SITEURL$/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You need work on Background Service.

Try below code.

```
public class BackgroundUpdateService extends Service {

    /**
     * Author：Hardik Talaviya
     * Date：  2019.08.3 2:30 PM
     * Describe:
     */

    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundLocation";
    private Context context;
    private boolean stopService = false;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder builder = null;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Background Service onCreate :: ");
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;

        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Add Here your code if you want start in background
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
                }
            }
        };
        if (!stopService) {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.e(TAG, "onTaskRemoved :: ");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand :: ");
        StartForeground();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "BackgroundService onDestroy :: ");
        stopService = true;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }

    /*-------- For notification ----------*/
    private void StartForeground() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_location";
        String CHANNEL_NAME = "channel_location";

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID);
            builder.setColorized(false);
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
            builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            builder.setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_NONE);
        } else {
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID);
        }
        builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
        builder.setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setContentText("Your Text");
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        builder.setSound(notificationSound);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification_app_icon);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        startForeground(101, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Add this line in your **Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<service
    android:name=".BackgroundUpdateService"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

And **Start & Stop** service from your activity using below code

```
Intent someIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundUpdateService.class);
startService(someIntent);//For start service
stopService(someIntent); //For stop service
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.